# lossless audio enconding

Tags: audio, file-compression, encoding, lossless

I am looking for a lossless audio encoder to archive huge amount of audio files.
Because it is for archive the encoding and decoding speed is not important at all (in a reasonable way - do not suggest an encoder that encode one minute of audio in a week).

I will using a computer to do encoding so compatibility is not an issue. I worked a lot with ffmpeg so I will be happy if it will be supported **but it is not mandatory at all**

requirement:

- Option to run via command line (as I will need to encode many files)
- High compression
- Prefer unix like (not mandatory).
- Open source

Comment: https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Lossless_comparison

Comment: Thanks for the link. Some of the encoders in the link does not working, are you sure that the article is up to date? Also the compression has been done with default settings, maybe there are better encoders with the right settings?